# how to permanently remove startup item in msconfig?

Tags: windows, system-administration

How to permanently remove the Startup items in Windows's msconfig?

(to start it, type Win+r, then msconfig. This is Windows Vista)

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you have to do this according to what is making the item start. So, remove the keys from the appropriate registry hive using regedit e.g. `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ *ProgramName*` (This is shown in the "location" column in msconfig.)

Answer (score 4):

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) has a built-in function for doing this

*(Tools -> Startup -> Choose desired item and press delete)*

Answer (score 0):

Hijack this has also this function built in.